# Where is the documentation for annotations in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I need to use annotations in spring boot. I've seen the api of spring boot, but all I can find is the package of the annotation.

I also try to find the use in spring boot reference, but that failed as well.

Comment: What are the names of the annotations that you are interested in?

Comment: I am interested in some basic annotations such as `@ComponentScan` `@Bean`  I want to know the detail use of these annotations